# CPU 100% Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: cpu, overheating, fan

The fan of my laptop was at full speed and I saw on the terminal with TOP comand that a process "thermald" was using 100% of one of my 2 CPU.
I had to reboot the laptop to get rid of that process.
What is the issue ?

Comment: LOL: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/ThermalIssues , "The **thermald** daemon prevents machines from overheating"

Comment: So my laptop was too hot, but the tempature didn't cool down even if no app were running ?

Comment: The deamon should prevent overheating... but in this case it was causing the overheating... I think it was just an error...